# Simultaneous Lorentz and Galilean invariance

Tags: special-relativity, maxwell-equations, galilean-relativity

The introduction of the Lorentz transformation is usually motivated by the Galilean failure when it comes to Maxwell's equations.

Are there physical systems that exhibit both Lorentz and Galileo invariance? If yes, what would the implications of such a situation be? Suppose now that Maxwell's equations form such a system. Would that have delayed the birth of special and general relativity ?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there physical systems that exhibit both Lorentz and Galileo invariance?

No, it is not possible for a system to exhibit both. In Galileo invariance there is no finite invariant speed and in Lorentz invariance there is one invariant speed and it is finite. Both statements cannot be true, i.e. there cannot both be one finite invariant speed and no finite invariant speed.

Comment: Well, technically, an object can be in the trivial representation of both the Galilean and the Lorentz groups. What one needs to show is that the two groups cannot share any non-trivial representation.

Comment: I am content to ignore that technicality on physical grounds